# Create a responsive rectangle div with CSS and Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate a full-width rectangle div on a website but I'm having problems with responsiveness and mobility.

Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3bX2.png) of what I'm trying to replicate.

And here's what I [have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQxTT.png) so far.

The problem is that the text won't go inside the separate boxes and it breaks in mobile version.

Here's my snippet:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row remove-container">
  <div class="speech-bubble1 test-text">
    <div class="row">
      <h3 class="strong-text felinetitle">ADD</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id="feline-ul">
        <li>
          <h6>Heartworm Test</h6>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h6>$25</h6>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="speech-bubble speech-bubble-top">
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 35px; padding-bottom: 35px;">
      <h3 class="strong-text felinetitle2">
        A LA CARTE </h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              DHPP or DHLPP
            </div>
           <div class="col-sm-6">
              Canine Flu
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #045faf;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.speech-bubble1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #045faf;
  width: 32%;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.remove-container {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.serviceprice {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.speech-bubble {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #045faf;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.speech-bubble1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #045faf;
    width: 32%;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.remove-container {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.serviceprice {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
#feline-ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#feline-ul li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
}

#feline-ul2{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#feline-ul2 li{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.test-text{
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 18px 0px 35px -23px rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
    box-shadow: 18px 0px 35px -23px rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
}
```

I'm having problems on the second box with my texts not compressing into a square/container. It just goes full width.

Comment: The HTML and CSS you provided results in [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/0jevLetc/), which is different from the picture. It would be easier if it matched the picture and if you told us exactly what was wrong with the functionality of it; what needs to be fixed.

Comment: And you should tell us if you use Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4 since this will make quite a huge difference.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recreated your structure to show you an minimal example.

*tl;dr; Your bootstrap code is not property nested.*

**What did i do?**
I wrapped the row into a container. A container is the element which wraps all rows in it. There is a `.container` and `.container-fluid` where the `.container-fluid` is for full-width layouts. Below a container is a row. A row is always split into 12 parts in bootstrap. You can specify the amount of columns for each display width. Read up on the width breakpoints at the [bootstrap grid doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options). You will NEVER want to have a `.row` with a nested `.row`. A row is always a parent of a column. If you resize my example you will notice that these two columns (`.col-md-8` and `.col-md-4`) are resizing to two 12-width column on small size devices.

And if you have key-value pairs as data i'd recommend to use tables instead of listings. This is just a semantical tip. A list covers just an enumeration like a shopping list. Instead a table is suited for object-like formatting (starting at one attribute): e.g. a dish which has a price.

```css
*{
  color: white;
}

footer{
  background-color: #045faf;
  padding: 20px;
}
#footer--left, #footer--right{
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#footer--left{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 18px 0px 35px -23px rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
    box-shadow: 18px 0px 35px -23px rgba(0,0,0,0.52);
}

table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div id="footer--left" class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Some Head Text</h3>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Value</td>
              <td>25$</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
      <div id="footer--right" class="col-md-8">
        <h3>Some Head Text</h3>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>25$</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This looks amazing, but is there a way to make the left footer full height?

Comment: Of course there is!
If you just want to remove the padding (the distance between `.footer--left`and the `.row`), just clear up the `padding` in `.footer`.
And also keep in mind that every heading has a default `margin-top` of 20px. You can override that with `h1, h2, h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, your example of code appears to me too overloaded. I would do in this way:

```css
.blocks {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.blocks .block {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 150px;
}
.blocks .block h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.blocks .block ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.blocks .block ul li {
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  margin: 0;
}
.blocks .block ul li:nth-child(1n) {
  display: inline;
}
.blocks .block:first-child {
  width: 33%;
}
.blocks .block:last-child {
  width: 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Add</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Service 1</li>
      <li>5$</li>
      <br>
      <li>Service 2</li>
      <li>10$</li>
      <br>
      <li>Service 3</li>
      <li>15$</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <h3>Add</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>Service 1</li>
      <li>5$</li>
      <br>
      <li>Service 2</li>
      <li>10$</li>
      <br>
      <li>Service 3</li>
      <li>15$</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```